# How to install poole/hyde in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap, hyde

I am trying to build a blog using Jekyll ( http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html) on github pages.

After publishing the site, a found a theme Hyde, that uses Poole (https://github.com/poole/poole/#readme).

I am finding it a bit tricky to install it over Jekyll. I hope someone can point me through.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rake theme:install git="https://github.com/jekyllbootstrap/theme-the-program.git"
```

Check out the API if you are having trouble or just drop it in the includes/themes/THEME-NAME

http://jekyllbootstrap.com/api/theme-api.html
http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-theming.html

Comment: The URLs are down here.